# Waiting for button press with multiple options

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I'm constructing a program and at some point, I need the user to make a choice. Using Tkinter windows and widgets, I'm attempting to have the user select their option by using one of 2 buttons. I know that there is `button.wait_waitvariable()` method, but I haven't been able to find a way for it to work on multiple buttons. Here, I've tried to create a work around for it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def press1():
    global myvar
    myvar.set(1)

def press2():
    global myvar
    myvar.set(2)

def main():
    global myvar
    print("Doing some other stuff that worked up until I added the next loop")

    myvar.set(0)
    while myvar.get()==0:
        #supposed to wait for a button to change value of myvar
        pass

    print(str(myvar.get())

root=Tk()
myvar=IntVar()
sbtn=Button(root,text="Start",command=main)
sbtn.grid(row=0,column=0)
btn1=Button(root,text="1",command=press1)
btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)
btn2=Button(root,text="2",command=press2)
btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

What ends up happening is that the window is created and (in this case) when `main()` is called, the window freezes (I assume it is stuck in the pass loop). None of the code executed before the pass loop is executed and, when I do a keyboard interrupt, traceback shows `while myvar.get==0:` as the most recent call.

Why does the inclusion of this loop cause the code above it to be ignored? Is there a way to have Tkinter wait on one of two buttons to be pressed?

Comment: `main()` will only be executed after the root window is closed, so how can an already closed window freeze?

Comment: Sorry, after typing out the parts that were important to the question, I just hastily added the main function. I will edit for better representation of the situation.

Comment: Replace the while loop by `root.wait_variable(myvar)`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the inclusion of this loop cause the code above it to be
> ignored? Is there a way to have Tkinter wait on one of two buttons to
> be pressed?

The way GUI frameworks such as tkinter works is not magic: once you are finished creating all the components, you pass the control to the framework, and it will take care of events and call your registered handler functions.
If you put such a `while` excpeting a change, it will never happen, because the loop, which would check for the mouse events in the operating system, animate the buttons, and call your callback functions to change the variable **is not running**. It will only be running once the execution gets to the `root.mainloop()` call (at which point, obviously, it can't be checking your `while` condition continuously).

There are even ways a program *could* be running in "two or more points at the same time" like you are imagining - the most straightforward translation is multi-threading programming. But one have to *know* what he is doing to make it work, not just pile things up and expect the magic to occur. And, often, GUI frameworks, tkinter included, won't work nicely with multi-threaded code (they can, again, if one know what he is doing).

The way one should think about building apps when using an event-drive framework, is to have functions that will be called in reaction to events.

So, although it is possible to create more or less what you are asking, that would be convoluted.

Just put the code you want to execute in each of the button presses in the functions `press1` or `press2` directly.

If there is common code, with a changing parameter, factor that out like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def press1():
    dothings(1)
    
def press2():
    dothings(2)

def dothings(parameter):
    # called when either button is pressed

def main():
    
    print("Doing some other stuff that worked up until I added the next loop")
    ... # create the UI, and only that. 
        # any program actions are triggered in callback functions.
```

Besides that, if there is some functionality the program should be doing continuously, such as monitoring the network, or a camera input - that code should be run in another thread, with a loop under your control, or, in a function that sets a time interval to be called back from the tkinter mainloop (use the `.after()` method from the root window). The main thread should be continuously run the tkinter mainloop, which will dispatch any needed events.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely hadn't thought to just use another function that the buttons call. This doesn't solve my problem right now, because I still need to find a way to wait for the input. I will likely have to re-approach this section with what you've provided in mind.

Comment: I just updated the answer with more context/information - please take a look again.

Comment: you don't have to "wait for the input": tkinter wiats for the input for you - your function, whcih should perform whatever task you need, will only be called when the input is provided.